# Xaml, button's click event runs before command?

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, uwp-xaml

(Now I'm Studying MVVM) I'm trying update current data(in a view model) with input data from UI.
But the problem is ViewModel doesn't know about the View. So that I can't access to input data in a UI (like TextBox.Text).

(below) In `MainPage.xaml` contains two TextBoxes to get input data
and a Button to Save input data

```
<StackPanel>
        <TextBox x:Name="NameTextBox" Margin="10" Header="Name text box" />
        <TextBox x:Name="AgeTextBox" Margin="10" Header="Age text box"/>

        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">

            <Button x:Name="SaveButton" Content="&#xE105;" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets"  Margin="30,10"
                     CommandParameter="{x:Bind ViewModel.CreatedPerson, Mode=OneWay}"
                     Command="{x:Bind ViewModel.SaveCommand}"
                     Click="SaveButton_Click"/>
        </StackPanel>

        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="20">
            <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind ViewModel.Person.Name, Mode=OneWay}" />
            <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind ViewModel.Person.Age, Mode=OneWay}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
```

`NameTextBox` and `AgeTextBox` holds input data until `SaveButton` is clicked.

(`Person` is plain data model with name and age properties)

> be aware : `SaveButton` above has `Command` and `Click` event both

(below) In `MainPageViewModel.cs` contains two properties and Command logic

```
public class MainPageViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public Person Person
    {
        get => _person;
        set { Set(nameof(Person), ref _person, value); }
    }
    private Person _person;

    public Person CreatedPerson
    {
        get => _createdPerson;
        set { Set(nameof(CreatedPerson), ref _createdPerson, value); }
    }
    private Person _createdPerson;

    public MainPageViewModel()
    {
        Person = new Person();
    }

    private RelayCommand<Person> _saveCommand;
    public RelayCommand<Person> SaveCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return _saveCommand
                ?? (_saveCommand = new RelayCommand<Person>(
                p =>
                {
                    Person.Name = p.Name;
                    Person.Age = p.Age;
                }));
        }
    }
}
```

`MainPageViewModel` contains `Person` and `CreatedPerson` properties.
`Person` property contains current data.
`CreatedPerson` property contains temporary data from UI.
If `SaveButton` is clicked `Person` property is updated.

(below) In `MainPage.xaml.cs` (code-behind file) has ViewModel and `SaveButton_Click` event

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    private readonly MainPageViewModel ViewModel = new MainPageViewModel();

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void SaveButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var newPerson = new Model.Person
        {
            Name = NameTextBox.Text,
            Age = Convert.ToInt32(AgeTextBox.Text)
        };
        ViewModel.CreatedPerson = newPerson;
    }
}
```

`SaveButton_Click` event gets data from TextBoxes and save them in a ViewModel.

My Question is how can I pass UI data(in a TextBox) as a parameter of `SaveCommand`? `MainPageViewModel` don't know about TextBoxes in the view.

To solve this problem, I create `SaveButton_Click` event in code-behind to access TextBoxes data. `SaveButton_Click` gets data from TextBoxes and Save them to The ViewModel(at CreatedPerson property).

After `CreatedPerson` is set, `SaveCommand` in the ViewModel executed to update `Person` property.

As a result, when the `SaveButton` is clicked, `SaveButton_Clicked` event fires before `SaveCommand`. So my project works fine anyway, But it smells a lot.

1. How can I solve this problem in a right way?
   Use converter?
   Now I'm trying to Use converter to pass `CommandParameter`, but stuck.
   `SaveCommand` need `Person` object as a parameter, and Person object need two data(name and age). how can I pass two parameter to a converter? using `Tuple`? :(
2. With curiousity, click event always fired before Command?

Answer (score 0):

Set the view model object from the constructor in the code behind class.

You shouldn't use both Command and Click-event.

Answer (score 0):

In your command you can use the parameter parameter (no phun intended)

```
public void Execute(object parameter)
{
    viewModel.Reply1 = new Models.Reports.Reply();
    viewModel.ShowList = false;
}
```

In your XAML you would provide that parameter as such:

```
    <Button Command="{Binding UpdateCommand}" CommandParameter="TheParameterYouWantoToUseInTheExecute"
```